# How to make a copy of a byte array in c code?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, image-processing, size

I have the address of the first char in my byte array, and it's size:
 const char *rawImageBytes, int size

And I want to copy the content to a different byte array. and then modify that one a bit.
This is whay I am doing now:

```
LOGI("FrameReceived will reach here 1");
modifiedRawImageBytes = rawImageBytes;
jint sizeWH = width * height;
jint quarter = sizeWH/4;
jint v0 = sizeWH + quarter;
for (int u = sizeWH, v = v0, o = sizeWH; u < v0; u++, v++, o += 2) {
        modifiedRawImageBytes[o] = rawImageBytes[v]; // For NV21, V first
        modifiedRawImageBytes[o + 1] = rawImageBytes[u]; // For NV21, U second
}
```

But I don't get the correct colours, as if I would to this in Java, instead of c++.
And I am assuming this happens, because I just do `modifiedRawImageBytes = rawImageBytes;` instead of actually copying the whole byte array, so that it can start in memory from another address pointer.
A bit of a beginner with c, so I'm lost at this, can someone help me understand what is done wrong?
PS: I am assuming that, because even if I send the rawImageBytes and not the modifiedRawImageBytes, it will still be modified

Comment: You tagged your question as C++, but the text says you're a beginner in C. So which language is it?

Comment: well JNI uses both C and C++ , and the code base it's written in both, so either one is good

Comment: *"so either one is good"* - Uh, but you do realise that C and C++ are two different languages, don't you? Surely you cannot work on that code without even knowing which programming language it is written in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `const char *` is a pointer. This mean it represent an address. So you guessed right, the new variable represent the same datas.

To avoid this you should create a copy.

```
char modifiedRawImageBytes[size];
//if the pointer come from function's param don't redeclare it ;)
std::memcpy(modifiedRawImageBytes, rawImageBytes, size*sizeof(char));
```

This code will allocate a new `char` array and then `memcpy` will copy in the previous array data in the new array.

Note that you need to include`cstdio`

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1. But why not just use `std::string modifiedRawImageBytes(rawImageBytes, size)`?

Comment: I used this:
`char *modifiedRawImageBytes = malloc(size);
 memcpy(modifiedRawImageBytes, rawImageBytes, size);`
Which does the same thing, and I don't need to include cstdio

Comment: Will still add this as the accepted answer, because the logic is pretty much the same.

Comment: @rosualin: It does not do the same thing at all. The code in the answer uses an array with automatic storage duration, your code uses dynamic allocation. You now have to manage deallocation manually, or you get memory leaks. If you use C++ and not C, then all of this is pretty much nonsense anyway.

Comment: @ChristianHackl If you do very low level stuff you may have no other choice.

Comment: @rosualin care that the pointer didn't own an other address. Indeed in C/C++ people might pass pointer to function to allow function modify the content of the pointer

Comment: Then it is c. I don't have access to cstdio. and yes, I know I have to dealloc, I use free(modifiedRawImageBytes).

Comment: @GuillaumeMILAN: There is no such thing as "C/C++", and of course you can use C++ for "very low level stuff", too. If you cannot use dynamic allocation for some reason, then `malloc` cannot be used either.